# Хочу сделать чтобы на кнопку F10 закрывалась программа

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать чтобы на кнопку F10 закрывалась программа C#

Comment: что пробовал и что не получилось?

Comment: поробуйте попробовать.

Comment: пробывал. В интернете нашел только одну статью. И то, не работает. Выдавало ошибку

Comment: Прочитайте [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=net-5.0) Попробуйте сделать сами, если не получится - размещайте здесь вопрос со своими попытками и Вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: Для начала надо опредилиться, что за программа. Винформс там, впф, юнити или еще что-то там типа ксамарина. Когда идешь к доктору и говоришь, что у тебя болит рука, он спрашивает - какая именно, и если не сказать, то он не сможет полечить. Вот и здесь так же. Телепаты конечно есть, но вы совсем сложную задачу выкатили по угадыванию типа приложения. Хотя телепатия подсказывает, что это винформс.

Comment: @Extend здесь не принято слать в гугл, чего и вам не советую делать. Иначе можно было бы на каждый вопрос слать, так как объективного критерия когда лучше слать, а когда не слать, не существует.

Comment: @aepot этот случай исключительный, во-первых вопрос максимально не уточненный, во-вторых не было отражено ни единой попытки собственноручно разобраться в вопросе

Comment: @Extend здесь каждый третий вопрос соответствует вашему описанию. И мы не шлем в гугл, даже если вообще всё плохо, даже если хуже, чем здесь. Нет критериев для принятия такого решения, этот метод не принят здесь. Просто примите мое замечание к сведению. Если вам не понравился вопрос, можно просто поставить минус. Участники с достаточным количеством репутации или модераторы его рано или поздно закроют, или удалят.

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, конечно приму к сведению. ps вопросик то закрыли

Answer (score 1):

Если речь о WinForms (из вопроса не совсем понятно, о чем речь), то очень просто. В свойствах главной формы устанавливаем KeyPreview = true (делать это нужно, чтобы форма реагировала на кнопочи вне зависимости от того, в каком элементе управления сейчас фокус).
В обработку событий этой же формы вставляем обработчик, допустим, на KeyUp. Внутри обработчика пишем:

```
private void ИМЯ_ФОРМЫ_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10)
        Application.Exit();
}
```

В WPF как-то еще проще делается, вроде есть стандартная команда для закрытия окна/приложения.
А вот как в консоли:

```
while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadKey();
    if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.F10)
        break; // можете использовать GOTO, если через выход из цикла не выходится
}
```